# How to search file on linux with like atribut?

Tags: linux, bash, opensuse

I want to find and delete log file on linux Terminal.

Usually I use this

> find -name '*.log'

after the File found, next use this script

> find -name '*.log' -type f -delete

that script work for

> filename.log

but now I want to find and delete file like this

```
mysqld.log-20180208  mysqld.log-20180223  mysqld.log-20180310  mysqld.log-20180325  mysqld.log-20180409
mysqld.log-20180123.xz  mysqld.log-20180209  mysqld.log-20180224  mysqld.log-20180311  mysqld.log-20180326  mysqld.log-20180410
mysqld.log-20180124.xz  mysqld.log-20180210  mysqld.log-20180225  mysqld.log-20180312  mysqld.log-20180327  mysqld.log-20180411
mysqld.log-20180125.xz  mysqld.log-20180211  mysqld.log-20180226  mysqld.log-20180313
```

How Can I find filename.log-12313

I want delete  filename.log- with number only.

Can anyone fix this?

thanks.

Im very appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already use globs; you can use them for any part of the file name:

```
find -name '*.log*' -type f -delete
```

Or if you want to be more specific:

```
find \( -name '*.log' -o -name '*.log-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' -o -name '*.log-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xz' \) -type f -delete
```

Comment: can it use except, exemple: except filename.log,

Comment: Yeah, there'll be questions about that here or at unix.SE.